# How to fire cash drawer closing event using CashDrawer Class (POS for .NET v1.12)

Tags: asp.net, .net, pos-for-.net

I am developing an POS application, I am able to open the cash drawer.

but I am not able to find the event when cash drawer is closed.

Please provide me code sample/ event which fire when cash drawer get closed.

Answer (score 0):

Listen to [OnDrawerStateChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.pointofservice.baseserviceobjects.cashdrawerbase.ondrawerstatechanged%28WinEmbedded.11%29.aspx)  event and inspect `DrawerStateChangedEventArgs.DrawerOpened` value. A `false` means closed. Per MSDN:

> The `CashDrawerBase` class raises `OnDrawerStateChanged` events to inform
>   the service object that the value of the
>   `CashDrawerProperties.DrawerOpened` property has been updated and the
>   application has been notified of a drawer status change. A
>   `DrawerStateChangedEventArgs.DrawerOpened` value of true indicates the
>   drawer status has changed to “open”; a
>   `DrawerStateChangedEventArgs.DrawerOpened` value of false indicates the
>   drawer status has changed to “closed”. Service objects should consider
>   implementing `OnDrawerStateChanged` when they want to be notified by the
>   `CashDrawerBase` class of drawer state changes.